# System calls, AWK, and Bringing in external inputs

Tags: text-processing, scripting, awk

```
awk '{ TEMPVAR="/usr/bin"; printf("%s", system("ls $TEMPVAR")); }' empty
```

In this example I'm trying to bring in the variable `TEMPVAR` into the `system` call. How would I do this?

What I'm aiming to do: I'm trying to use `date -d $0 +%s` in a `system` call that occurs every line of a file. However, I'm struggling with how to get that `$0` value into the system call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`awk` can access environment variables using the `ENVIRON` special array. However, while you can assign values to elements of that array, it is not passed in the environment of the commands executed by `awk`'s `system`, `| getline` or `print |`. That `ENVIRON` array is only intended for `awk` to **get** the value of the environment variables it is passed.

You can do: `system("ls " var)`, but beware that the string that is passed to `awk`'s `system()` (or `print |` or `| getline`) is actually passed as an argument to `sh -c`, so it is interpreted as shell code.

For instance, if the `awk` `var` variable contains `foo;rm -rf /`, it will not tell `ls` to list the file called `"foo;rm -rf /"` but instead to list the file called `foo` and then the `rm` command will be run.

So, you may need to escape all the characters special to the shell in that `var` variable.

This could be done for instance with:

```
awk '
  function escape(s) {
    gsub(/'\''/, "&\\\\&&", s)
    return "'\''" s "'\''"
  }
  {
    cmd = "date -d " escape($0) " +%s"
    cmd | getline seconds
    close(cmd)
    print seconds
  }'
```

While that means running one shell and one `date` command per line, you might as well do the reading of the file with the shell itself:

```
while IFS= read <&3 -r line; do
  date -d "$line" +%s
done 3< the-file
```

Comment: For future readers that wonder why so many quotes and backslashes are used, this is because the snippet *is a **shell command too*. What you basically need to do is to put single quotes around the argument and substitute the single quotes in the argument by `'\''` (end string, insert `\'`, continue string). In an AWK script (file), it is sufficient to use `gsub(/'/, "'\\''", s); return "'" s "'";`, but for a "one-liner" command, the single quotes and backslashes must be escaped again as shown by Stephane.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing an Awk variable to *system*, you need to shell quote it:

```
function quote(str,   d, m, x, y, z) {
  d = "\47"; m = split(str, x, d)
  for (y in x) z = z d x[y] d (y < m ? "\\" d : "")
  return z
}
```

Example:

```
system(sprintf("date -d %s +%%s", quote($0)))
```

[Source](//github.com/svnpenn/stdlib/blob/3216068/stdlib.awk#L26-L32)